# "Servers" view missing from Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to configure Tomcat with Eclipse Indigo, but the "Servers" view is missing. That being said, I had to follow [this](http://www.howtosolvenow.com/2011/07/tomcat-configuration-in-eclipse-indigo/) tutorial on how to configure Tomcat with Eclipse Indigo using plugins. The plugins work, but I would like to find out why the "Servers" view is missing in the first place.

Eclipse specs:

```
Version: 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK
Build id: M20110909-1335
```

Tomcat specs:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
Server built: Sep 27 2011 09:40:50
Server number: 7.0.22.0
OS Name: Windows XP
OS Version: 5.1
Architecture: x86
JVM Version: 1.6.0_20-b02
```

OS specs:

```
Microsoft Windows XP
Professional
Version 2002
Service Pack 3
```

And if it matters, [this](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/) is the tutorial I was originally following.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Is it missing just from the menu maybe?

If you goto "Window > Show View > Other..." and then type Servers in the filter, does it show up?

Also make sure you downloaded the "Eclipse For Java EE Developers" package as I do not believe the "Eclipse for Java Developers" contains the Servers view.

Eclipse for Java EE Developers:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1

Comment: I had a bug where the view was not showing up even after doing "Window > Show View > Other...", I had to switch perspective and then come back to a "Java EE" perspective to get the "Server" view back for some reason. Eclipse does have bugs... it's only about knowing them most of times.

Comment: I had to switch to the Java EE perspective and then back to my regular perspective in order to get the Servers view to show up.

Comment: If I want just to install Java EE on top of my current eclipse (I program in android) how should I do it?

Comment: Look for java ee perspective, if you do not have java ee perspective(you'll see java as default perspective), you can install the java ee suite using help-install new software - give link http://download.eclipse.org/releases/<YourRelease> and expand the options that you get. select all the java ee related packages that you need and install.

Comment: Reinstall Eclipse is not an option, therefore I prefer shivakiran's solution of adding the Java EE plugins.

Answer (score 25):

I am using Luna. I have following following steps.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Choose "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" site
3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
4. Select    i)  Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools    3.6.3.v201501281502
            ii) Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools   3.6.3.v201502041526
            iii)    Eclipse Web Developer Tools    3.6.3.v201501312139
5. Restart Eclipse.

Not sure if it works for indigo or not. If not, you need to search for the URL for indigo in http://download.eclipse.org/releases.

Comment: +1 , By default fedora or some linux distros install only java version of eclipse. The above steps will help on these cases.

Answer (score 5):

It's late but someone may get help with this...

There is a option to reset perspective and you can get all view as before.

First select the perspective you want to reset then use the window menu to find the "Reset Perspective" option.

window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective

Comment: this won't work unless you have the components listed in the accepted answer.

Comment: Works, thank you: Be prepared to reconfigure everything to how you want as this resets the perspective back to its original (default) layout.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Eclipse Neon please follow this steps.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Choose "Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon" site
3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development"
4. Select JST Server Adapters and JST Server Adapters Extentions
5. Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After accept the license and click install please look bottom right corner, there you can notice you software is downloading after download only you have to restart the IDE :)